# UpdatePanel and document.ready() Sys.Application.add_load not adding handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I want my div to visible on the basis of `HiddenFiled` value. So I did the following:

**ASPX**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Sys.Application.add_load(BindEvents);
     </script>
        <div id="addPopUp" runat="server" style="padding: 30px; height: auto; width: 450px;
            overflow: hidden; display: none; background-color: White; border: 1px solid black;">
            <table width="500px;">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" align="left" style="width: 27%;">
                        <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hfLevel" />
                        <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hfLevel1Id" />
                        <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hfLevel2Id" />
                        <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hfLevel3Id" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 80%;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 20%;" align="left" class="topics">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 80%;">
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="radAdd" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" GroupName="ModeAddEdit"
                            Text="Add Link" Checked="true" OnCheckedChanged="radAdd_CheckedChanged" />
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="radEdit" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" GroupName="ModeAddEdit"
                            Text="Edit Link" OnCheckedChanged="radEdit_CheckedChanged" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 20%;" align="left" class="topics">
                        <strong>Link Name :</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 80%;">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLinkName" CssClass="txtbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 20%;" class="topics">
                        <strong>Url :</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 80%;">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUrl" CssClass="txtbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 20%;" class="topics">
                        <strong>Position :</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 80%;">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPosition" CssClass="txtbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 20%;" class="topics">
                        <strong>Show on same page :</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 80%;">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSamePage" runat="server" Checked="true" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td class="topics" align="left">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="sfCustomButton" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:Button ID="btnHide" runat="server" Text="Hide Link" CssClass="sfCustomButton" />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <input type="button" id="btnCancel" value="Cancel" class="sfCustomButton" onclick="hide()" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="radAdd" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="radEdit" />
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" />
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnHide" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and 
**CODE BEHIND**

```
 protected void radAdd_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hfShow.Value = "1";
        }

        protected void radEdit_CheckedChanged(Object sender,  EventArgs e)
        {
            hfShow.Value = "1";
        }
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  function BindEvents() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var hf = document.getElementById("hfShow"); alert(hf.value);
            if (hf.value == "1") {
                Popup.showModal('addPopUp', null, null, { 'screenColor': '#cccccc', 'screenOpacity': .6 });
            }
        });
    }
```

I am helpless to find the issue behind why `alert(hf.value);` is not working, I guess 
`Sys.Application.add_load(BindEvents);` is not working, Anyone knows why its not working ?
Thanks.

Comment: its working but you give hidden field value on radio button checked change event so document.ready function works on page load so on load you get noting. when you want exactly the hidden field value.? @DND

Comment: I need hidden field value when when contents inside UpdatePanel loads. means after `AsyncPostBack`.

Comment: when you want to open the content inside the update panel.it means any click or any button or on load ?@DND

Comment: Basically I have some dynamic link, after clicking on that link, div inside `UpdatePanel` open, this div have two radio button and after clicking any of them show keep div open, rest of things are clear in code.

Comment: then you can set hidden field value on that dynamic link and maintining same value on radio button checked change.@DND